# List comprehension within if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, list-comprehension

I'm trying to get my head around list comprehension at the moment, and trying to build a blackkack game using as much of it as possible. Im stuck at this particular point:

```
   elif card == (char for char in ["K", "J", "Q"]):
        print("Detected facecard")
```

I understand it would possibly be easier to use a dictionary or some alternative method, or even just expand the loop out, but I'm specifically trying to understand why this wont work.

printing char for char in .... yields the object type rather than the objects.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just `elif card in ['K', 'J', 'Q']:` ??

Comment: `card` is never going to equal the generator. If you *really* want to write it like that, maybe something like `if any(char == card for char in [...]):`.

Comment: Also, go easy on the listcomps, it's very normal to overuse it

Comment: Yeah i can see I'll start overusing them, its just something i want to practice, particularly the double loops. Thanks for the help everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What vurmux commented is the proper way to do it, but here's why what you did won't work:

`(char for char in ["K", "J", "Q"])` is a generator, and so what's actually happening is that python is comparing `card` to that generator, which will always be false.

```
>> x = (char for char in ["K", "Q", "J"])
>> print(x)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f10752d4410>
```

Comment: Yeah I understood that, just couldnt get why it was producing a generator

Comment: That's what the paranthesis `()` around the statement does. If instead you did `[char for char in ["K", "Q", "J"]]`, it would redudantly generate the list `["K", "Q", "J"]`.

Comment: Thats the exact answer I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`(char for char in ["K", "J", "Q"])` constructs the generator:

> `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f97e9f8f200>`

So you are trying to compare a card (I think it is not a generator :) ) with generator. It always will be `False`. You can just check that `card` is in `["K", "J", "Q"]`:

`elif card in ['K', 'J', 'Q']:`